# How ArrayList in this program printing the elements without any loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

How does the following program prints the element contained in ArrayList without using any loop

```
import java.util.*;  

class Abc{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();  
  al.add("Ravi");  
  al.add("Vijay");  
  al.add("Ravi");  
  al.add("Ajay");  

    System.out.println(al);  
 }  
}
```

Output : [Ravi, Vijay, Ravi, Ajay]

Comment: you are printing object of arraylist. and it prints all elements in array list

Comment: `ArrayList` inherits a `toString()` method with a loop in it from `AbstractCollection`.

Comment: I think you can't avoid using a loop. How should you know what's in the list without iterating it?

Comment: @TheLostMind Which uses iterator and a loop ;)

Comment: @TheLostMind You caught me in the ten seconds I was looking it up.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - Yep.. Thats right :)

Comment: @khelwood - I have no idea what you are talking about :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ArrayList` by itself doesn't have a `toString()` method. It extends `AbstractList` which inturn extends `AbstractCollection` which defines the actual ['toString'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) method.

From java docs :

toString

```
public String toString()
```

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string
>   representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
>   order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
>   ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma
>   and space). Elements are converted to strings as by
>   String.valueOf(Object).

```
Overrides:
toString in class Object
Returns:
a string representation of this collection
```

Answer (score 2):

Think of the line:

```
System.out.println(al);
```

As really being

```
System.out.println(al.toString());
```

The toString method is inherited from AbstractCollection.

If your interested in what is going on behind the AbstractCollection's toString method ...

[image]

link: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29

Answer (score 0):

It is using a loop, but not in the code that you are showing, but in the method `toString()` that `ArrayList` inherits from `AbstractCollection` which is one of its ancestor classes.

Whenever you pass an object to `print()` or `println()`, what actually happens is that `print()` calls `String.valueOf()` passing it that object.

This, in turn, if the object passed is not null, calls the object`s`toString` method.

`AbstractCollection` has a `toString` method that relies on iterating and calling the `toString` methods of each item inside the collection it represent.

So there is a loop there, but it`s buried inside a method that calls a method that calls a method.

Answer (score 0):

Because ArrayList is written in Java which has it's own implementation. So that's why when you user toString() then it will print your elements.

But if you try to use toString() with Array then it will not work.
Because array is part of languate specification.

Hope this will helps you :)